# Execute PowerShell on Azure VM from TFS via AzureRM

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have a number of VMs provisioned in my Azure subscription, protected by an NSG, so I don't have WinRM available remotely.

I'd like to execute a PowerShell script on these VMs as part of my TFS release definition.

Is there any way to execute arbitrary PowerShell scripts on Azure VM resources?

I'm aware of the Custom Script extension for Azure VM resources, but I don't know if this is what I'm after, or if it plays nicely with TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Script Extension would work fine for running scripts on the VM - but it would have to be done as part of "adding" the extension.  Meaning you'd have to deploy the extension to the VM to trigger running the script.  So you'd do it when the VM is provisioned or submit another deployment to run the script after it's provision.

Either is doable from TFS/VSTS...

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured this out a few hours after I posted the question. It’s pretty cool, except the whole thing seems to block until complete and doesn’t stream the output to the console realtime. Could be annoying for long running processes.

Comment: Which output - the output from the VSTS build task?  or the script running on the VM?

Comment: The script running in the VM. It would be useful to pipe its output back to TFS so I could see what it’s doing during deployment.

Comment: Ah... yes, getting output from the custom script extension can be tricky, but short answer - no piping to TFS yet.

Comment: Ok, so last question before this becomes a separate thread - will the exit code from the script extension inform TFS of pass/fail? Thanks!

Comment: If the script has a failure exit code, it will send a failure for the custom script extension resource in the overall deployment and VSTS will see that failure.